# Persistir JSON Postgres / Golang

Tags: json, postgresql, golang

Olá, há algum modo de persistir um JSON no postgres com a linguagem GO?

Não quero fazer um insert manual, quero mapear meu JSON com um struct e persistir, similar ao hibernate em Java.

encontrei essa lib http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson

Converto meu JSON em BSON e persisto?

Como ficaria isso no código?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate é um [ORM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional).  Para Go, são 4 [opções mais populares](http://jmoiron.net/blog/golang-orms/):

- [gorp](http://github.com/coopernurse/gorp)
- [beedb](http://github.com/beedb/beedb)
- [hood](https://github.com/eaigner/hood)
- [qbs](https://github.com/coocood/qbs)

Eu nunca os usei... E o mais provável, eu nunca vou.  Eu, como muitos desenvolvedores, decidi que ORMs não são geralmente úteis. Eu prefiro escrever meu próprio SQL, porque não é difícil, me dá melhor controle, que muitas vezes dá um melhor desempenho, e significa que eu sempre entender o que meu código está fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) e é bem fácil de mexer.

Depois que dá uma lida vai entender, é algo assim, você pode usar o BSON para gerar sua string UUID

```
type Modelo struct {
    UUID string `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Payload string `sql:"type:JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::JSONB"`
}

db.Save(&modelo)
```

Para o campo payload vc faz um json.Marshal();